# Laravel 5 - tabela de banco de dados para array com index pré-definido

Tags: query, laravel-5

Existe alguma maneira de recuperar os resultados de uma query no banco de dados e trasformá-la numa `Array` com um dos campos da tabela sendo index da `Array`?

Poderia conseguir esse resultado em duas etapas. Depois da query faz um `loop` e transforma na `Array` com índex desejado.

Tem como ober esse resultado em uma etapa?

Esse é o código que me retorna a *query*:

```
$lang = DB::table('language')->select('id', 'name')->get();
```

Eu queria que `$lang` fosse uma array do tipo `$lang[id=>name]`.

Comment: São só dois campos?

Comment: para essa query sim,  mas tem outras com mais de dois. A lógica deve ser a mesma não?

Comment: Se você for iterar sim, mas para casos de dois campos o Laravel tem o `lists`

Comment: exato. lists funciona bem para 2 campos. valeu

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::lists()](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/155610/call-to-undefined-method-illuminate-database-query-builderlists)

Comment: Exemplos: [link1](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/155619/54880), [link2](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/167411/54880), [link3](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/180078/54880) e [link4](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/180828/54880)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tenta usar a função **[pluck](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-pluck)**

```
$lang = DB::table('language')->select('id', 'name')->pluck('name', 'id')->toArray();
```