# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::lists()

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-eloquent, laravel-collective

Estou com um problema em criar uma lista de tipos para meu projeto, por algum motivo em outros **`Controller`** funcionou perfeitamente porém neste infelizmente não.

Estou fazendo o método `create` do meu `Controller`

```
public function create()
{
    $celula = new Celula();
    $tipos = TipoCelula::where('COD_IDENT_IGREJ', Auth::user()
                           ->COD_IDNET_IGREJ)->lists('TXT_NOMEX_TIPOX','COD_TIPOX_CELUL');
    $igreja = Igreja::find(Auth::user()->COD_IDENT_IGREJ);
    return view('Celula.cadCelula', compact('celula', 'tipos', 'igreja'));
}
```

Meu relacionamento em Tipo - Célula se da da seguinte forma, existem vários tipos porém cada igreja tem seus tipos próprios por isto estou selecionando so os que tem o código da igreja condizente com o que estou passando, cada tipo deste pode ser de uma célula porém cada célula tem apenas um tipo deste. Baseado nisto meus `models` ficarão assim:

***Model Celula***

```
public function tipo(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\TipoCelula', 'COD_TIPOX_CELUL', 'COD_TIPOX_CELUL');
}
```

***Model Tipo***

```
public function celulas(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Celula', 'COD_TIPOX_CELUL', 'COD_TIPOX_CELUL');
}
```

Com todo este processo feito em minha view estou tentando lista os tipos da seguinte forma:

```
{!! Form::select('COD_TIPOX_CELUL', $tipos, $celula->COD_TIPOX_CELUL, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Selecione uma opção']) !!}
```

O que está havendo com meu programa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O método `lists` é ***`obsoleta`*** (`deprecated`) e foi substituido por [`pluck`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#method-pluck) segundo [`Upgrading To 5.2.0 From 5.1`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/upgrade#upgrade-5.2.0), e na versão [`5.3`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/) foi removida.
Na verdade só houve uma alteração no nome o resto é igual ao anterior `lists`.

### Deprecations

***The following features are deprecated in 5.2 and will be removed in the 5.3 release in June 2016:***

> - Illuminate\Contracts\Bus\SelfHandling contract. Can be removed from jobs.
> - The lists method on the Collection, query builder and Eloquent query builder objects has been renamed to pluck. The method signature
>     remains the same.
> - Implicit controller routes using Route::controller have been deprecated. Please use explicit route registration in your routes
>     file. This will likely be extracted into a package.
> - The get, post, and other route helper functions have been removed. You may use the Route facade instead.
> - The database session driver from 5.1 has been renamed to legacy-database and will be removed. Consult notes on the "database
>     session driver" above for more information.
> - The Str::randomBytes function has been deprecated in favor of the random_bytes native PHP function.
> - The Str::equals function has been deprecated in favor of the hash_equals native PHP function.
> - Illuminate\View\Expression has been deprecated in favor of Illuminate\Support\HtmlString.
> - The WincacheStore cache driver has been removed.

---

***No seu código seria:***

```
public function create()
{

    $celula = new Celula();

    $tipos = TipoCelula::where('COD_IDENT_IGREJ', Auth::user()->COD_IDNET_IGREJ)
                         ->pluck('TXT_NOMEX_TIPOX','COD_TIPOX_CELUL');

    $igreja = Igreja::find(Auth::user()->COD_IDENT_IGREJ);

    return view('Celula.cadCelula', compact('celula', 'tipos', 'igreja'));

}
```

***Referencia:***

- https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/upgrade#upgrade-5.2.0
- [->lists() deprecated? Replacement?](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/lists-deprecated-replacement)

Comment: Como seria meu caso na nova versão ?

Comment: Fiz a edição @RenanRodrigues com o código! só mudou mesmo o nome do método.