# Popular select com valores do banco de dados

Tags: php, laravel

Preciso popular um select no formulário com valores de uma outra tabela. Tipo:

```
<select>
   <option value="29">Frentista</option>
</select>
```

Escrevi meu select assim:

```
{{ Form::select('set_id_fk', $setores, null, ['class'=>'form-control input-lg']) }}
```

Mas na view está ficando assim:

```
{"set_id": 29, "set_nome": "Frentista"}
```

Estou usando o `"laravelcollective/html": "^5.3.0"` no meu projeto.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: O seu `Laravel` é o 5.3?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::lists()](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/155610/call-to-undefined-method-illuminate-database-query-builderlists)

Comment: me diga a versão do seu `Laravel` e o `model Eloquent` com os campos para postar uma solução, apesar que sua duvida já pode existir uma duplicata (pergunta que já contem algum resposta que também pode solucionar seu problema), eu percebi que você postou na resposta abaixo mas, no meu comentário não fez nenhum comentário! eu posso te ajudar claro, se quiser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você possui uma tabela com os tipos e identificadores únicos fica fácil, supondo que eu tenha a seguinte tabela:

```
id descricao
1   Álcool
2   Gasolina
3   Disel
```

e a partir disto tenha meu modelo criado, supondo o nome do modelo TipoCombustivel, para montar o array de itens basta utilizar o método pluck da seguinte forma:

```
$arrayTipoCombustivel = App\Models\TipoCombustivel::pluck('descricao', 'id');
```

nisto, eu teria o $arrayTipoCombustivel desse modo

```
[
 '1' => 'Álcool',
 '2' => 'Gasolina',
 '3' => 'Disel'
]
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Answer (score 1):

Quando voce recuperar os dados tente transformar ele em uma lista da seguinte forma:

```
$associados = Associado::all()->lists('associado','id');
```

O list transforma o resultado em um array com KEY e Valor, o primeiro parâmetro é o que você deseja aparecer no Select, e a key sera o valor da dentro do select.

Como fica:

```
<option value="id">associado</option>
```

Comment: Tentei desta forma e acusou os seguinte erro: BadMethodCallException in Macroable.php line 74:
Method lists does not exist.

Comment: Sua classe deve externder do Eloquent.
Se puder mandar a copia da classe que carrega a variave $setores

Comment: Entendi. Este código está no controller que extends de Controller. No caso devo criar o método no model que extends de Eloquent correto?