# htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Tags: html, mysql, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-5.3

Eu estou tentando fazer um botão `select` no blade com `@foreach` pra pegar a lista de todas as bases de dados do MySql. Só o `@foreach` funciona, eu consigo pegar os valores, mas não estou conseguindo colocar as bases dentro de um `select`. Está dando erro:

> htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given(View: C:\Gerador\resources\views\geradors\create.blade.php)

Meu controller:

```
public function create(Request $request)
{
    $tables = DB::select('SHOW TABLES');
    //dd($tables);
    //GeradorController->criacontroller($request);
    return view("geradors.create",['tables'=>$tables]);
}
```

Minha View:

```
<div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Tabelas:</div>
        @foreach($tables as $table)
        {{ $table }}
        @endforeach
        <select name="tables">
        {!! Form::select('table', $table, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
        </select>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Os dados para funcionar com `Form::select` precisa ser um `array` com ***chave*** e ***valor***, *exemplo*:

```
$array = [key1 => valor1, key2 => valor2];
```

então formate os dados assim no seu `controller`:

```
public function create(Request $request)
{
    //Lista todas as Base de Dados de um Banco MySQL
    $tables = DB::select('SHOW DATABASES');

    //Para utilizar no Select utilize o função "collect" e o método "pluck"
    $selectDb = collect($tables)
                        ->pluck('Database','Database')
                        ->toArray();

    return view("geradors.create",[
        'tables'=>$tables, 
        'selectDb' => $selectDb
        ]
    )
}
```

na `view`:

```
<div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Tabelas:</div>
        @foreach($tables as $table)
        {{ $table->Database }}
        @endforeach

        {!! Form::select('table', $selectDb, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}

        </div>
</div>
```