# GetType() Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, funções, laravel-5

Estou tentando pegar o tipo das colunas das tabelas do meu `BD`, e como pode-se utilizar `PHP` com o `Laravel` eu tentei usar o `GetType` para pegar os tipos e mostrar na `view`. Porem o código está retornando somente `Object`.
Segue o código:

> Controller

```
$input = $request->all();
$tables = $request->input('tables');
$resultados = DB::select('select * from ' .$tables);

$colunas = array();
foreach($resultados as $resultado){
    echo (getType($resultado));
    $colunas[] = ((array)$resultado);
}
dd($colunas);
```

> View

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        {!! Form::label('tables', 'Tabelas:', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
        <br><br>
            <select class="selectpicker form-control" name="tables" id="tables">
                <option disabled selected> -- Selecione -- </option>
                    @foreach($tables as $table)
                        @foreach ($table as $key => $value)
                            <option value="{{ $value }}">{{ $value }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                     @endforeach
            </select>
    </div>
```

Existe alguma outra maneira de pegar o tipo?

Comment: você precisa dos tipos que estão na tabela do seu Banco? o que vem em `$tables` (é o nome de uma tabela)?

Comment: O que vem em `$tables` sãos as colunas da tabela que eu selecionar no meu banco. O que eu preciso agora é pegar o tipo de cada coluna. Ex: int, varchar.

Comment: Um `DESC tabela` não resolveria? vai listar o nome, tipo e as opções (primary key, permite nulo, valor padrão etc) da coluna.

Comment: Lara `O que vem em $tables sãos as colunas da tabela` me cite exemplos que vem dentro dessa variável?

Comment: Virgilio, minha `tabela` chama `Tabelas`, dentro dela eu tenho: `Id`, `tabela`, `campo`, `tipo` e `pesquisa`. E eu quero pegar o tipo de cada campo. Entendeu?
E Rray, eu não sei se DESC tabela resolveria porque não tentei. Irei tentar.

Comment: Agora eu entendi Lara, porque, o seu código com um s no final causava para mim confusão, bom a resposta acredito que responde o que precisa, por favor dê uma olhada

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Utilize [describe](http://imasters.com.br/artigo/7446/mysql/mysql-describe/?trace=1519021197&source=single) no [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) informando o nome da tabela, exemplo:

```
$table = 'user'; // nome da tabela
$resultados = DB::select('describe ' .$table);

// vai mostrar todos os campos de um determinada tabela 
// com seus tipos e informações extras.
dd($resultados);
```

Saída:

```
>>> $result = DB::select('describe credits');
=> [
     {#678
       +"Field": "id",
       +"Type": "int(10) unsigned",
       +"Null": "NO",
       +"Key": "PRI",
       +"Default": null,
       +"Extra": "auto_increment",
     },
     {#679
       +"Field": "name",
       +"Type": "varchar(50)",
       +"Null": "NO",
       +"Key": "",
       +"Default": null,
       +"Extra": "",
     },
     {#680
       +"Field": "created_at",
       +"Type": "timestamp",
       +"Null": "YES",
       +"Key": "",
       +"Default": null,
       +"Extra": "",
     },
     {#681
       +"Field": "updated_at",
       +"Type": "timestamp",
       +"Null": "YES",
       +"Key": "",
       +"Default": null,
       +"Extra": "",
     },
     {#664
       +"Field": "active",
       +"Type": "tinyint(1)",
       +"Null": "NO",
       +"Key": "",
       +"Default": "1",
       +"Extra": "",
     },
   ]
```

---

Somente a coluna `Type`:

```
$result = collect(DB::select('describe credits'))->pluck('Type');
```

Saída

```
=> Illuminate\Support\Collection {#674
     all: [
       "int(10) unsigned",
       "varchar(50)",
       "timestamp",
       "timestamp",
       "tinyint(1)",
     ],
   }
```

<sub>***Referencias:***</sub>

- [MySQL – Describe](http://imasters.com.br/artigo/7446/mysql/mysql-describe/?trace=1519021197&source=single)
- [MySQL – Comandos SHOW, DESCRIBE e mysqlshow](http://www.bosontreinamentos.com.br/mysql/mysql-comandos-show-describe-e-mysqlshow-39/)

Comment: @LaraGallassi pronto ...